# How to get tablenames from the following in python

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I am using big query client with python to retrieve the table names from big query.

```
  result  = client._get_all_tables(datasetID,cache=False)
  print result
     for x in result:
```

The result is as follows,

```
{u'totalItems': 7, u'tables': [{u'kind': u'bigquery#table', u'type': u'TABLE', u'id': u'publicdata:samples.github_nested', u'tableReference': {u'projectId': u'publicdata', u'tableId': u'github_nested', u'datasetId': u'samples'}}, {u'kind': u'bigquery#table', u'type': u'TABLE', u'id': u'publicdata:samples.github_timeline', u'tableReference': {u'projectId': u'publicdata', u'tableId': u'github_timeline', u'datasetId': u'samples'}}, {u'kind': u'bigquery#table', u'type': u'TABLE', u'id': u'publicdata:samples.gsod', u'tableReference': {u'projectId': u'publicdata', u'tableId': u'gsod', u'datasetId': u'samples'}}, {u'kind': u'bigquery#table', u'type': u'TABLE', u'id': u'publicdata:samples.natality', u'tableReference': {u'projectId': u'publicdata', u'tableId': u'natality', u'datasetId': u'samples'}}, {u'kind': u'bigquery#table', u'type': u'TABLE', u'id': u'publicdata:samples.shakespeare', u'tableReference': {u'projectId': u'publicdata', u'tableId': u'shakespeare', u'datasetId': u'samples'}}, {u'kind': u'bigquery#table', u'type': u'TABLE', u'id': u'publicdata:samples.trigrams', u'tableReference': {u'projectId': u'publicdata', u'tableId': u'trigrams', u'datasetId': u'samples'}}, {u'kind': u'bigquery#table', u'type': u'TABLE', u'id': u'publicdata:samples.wikipedia', u'tableReference': {u'projectId': u'publicdata', u'tableId': u'wikipedia', u'datasetId': u'samples'}}], u'kind': u'bigquery#tableList', u'etag': u'"hnk59tKBkX8cdlePZ8VtzgVzuO4/2P51RdhDvk7tUvXpY_uairNEWDE"'}
```

How to get the tablenames from the above dictionary list?

**Expected Output:**

```
github_nested
github_timeline
gsod
natality
shakespeare
trigrams
wikipedia
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done in the following way,

```
tablesWithDetails =    result["tables"]
      print tablesWithDetails
      for inditable in tablesWithDetails:
          tables.append(inditable["id"])
      return tables
```